# LiveCD mounts the partitions, but it doesn't see any

Tags: 10.10, installation, partitioning, live-cd, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 from Live CD.
I can access the partitions already created ( two NTFS and one ext3 prepared ), but when I'm trying to install, at the step where I should select the partition, I don't have from where to choose.
The list is empty, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

My HDD is @ S-ATA. 
Motherboard: AsRock ConRoeXFire-eSATA2

Comment: Open GParted, System>Administration>GParted and take a screenshot of your partition set up please.

Comment: A mounted partition would (probably) not be accessible to the installer. Try unmounting it first.

Answer (score 1):

"I can access the partitions already created" -- does that mean you mounted them?

The installer doesn't like your volumes mounted - gparted will error.

I suggest setting up a new partition table with the installer, as long as it not gonna mess up your Windows partition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mount
```

will show you all your mounted partitions

```
$ umount /dev/[sda*]
```

repace [sda*] with your disk/partition identifier. 
will umount your partition.

`umount` the partitions to get access to them in the installer.

Or right click the partitions in nautilus and click umount them to make them available in the installer.